# How to inject model if the model is in the root module only

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I want to inject a mongo db model in NestJS Service. The model is present in the root module only.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { IFolderModel } from './interfaces/folder.interface';

@Injectable()
export class FolderService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('IFolder') private folderModel: Model<IFolderModel>) {

    }

    async create(folderInstance: IFolderModel): Promise<IFolderModel> {
       const folderModelToBeSaved = new this.folderModel(folderInstance);
       return await folderModelToBeSaved.save();
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<IFolderModel[]> {
       return await this.folderModel.find().exec();
    }
}
```

I am getting following error while starting application using `npm run start`

`Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FolderService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.`

Contents of AppModule

```
 let mongodb = env.mongodb;
 let url = `mongodb://${mongodb.user}:${mongodb.pwd}@${mongodb.host}:${mongodb.port}/${mongodb.dbName}`;

 @Module({
    imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot(url)],
    controllers: [AppController, FolderController],
    providers: [AppService, FolderService],
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to additionally import your schemas with `MongooseModule.forFeature`. Usually, you would set up the database connection in the root module and then import the schemas in dedicated feature modules. This is why the imports are separate.

```
MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Folder', schema: FolderSchema }])
```

For further information, see the [mongo docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb).

Comment: If a dedicated feature is not created, is there a way I can import schema?

Comment: Just do the `MongooseModule.forFeature` import in the same module as the `forRoot` import. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the imports array of your module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'FolderName', schema: FolderSchema }]),
  ],
})
```